# How to synchronize SpeechSynthesis and Text Color Changes in Web Project

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

I'm currently working on a web project using the SpeechSynthesis API to read paragraphs of text on a webpage. I've been trying to synchronize the spoken words with the color changes in the text, but I'm facing some challenges.

Here's a brief overview of the issue:

- I have a function that reads out the content of

  tags on a page using the SpeechSynthesis API.
- The goal is to synchronize the spoken words with color changes in real-time.
- Specifically, I'd like each word to change to red while it's being spoken and revert to the original color when the word is completed.
- every attempt led to the whole paragraph being red.

My working code without the sync is below.

```
function speakAllParagraphs(page) {
  // Get all <p> elements within the current page
  var paragraphs = document
    .getElementById("page" + page)
    .getElementsByTagName("p");

  // Iterate through each <p> tag
  Array.from(paragraphs).forEach(function (paragraph, index) {
    // Speak the text of the paragraph
    var text = paragraph.innerText;

    // Create a new SpeechSynthesisUtterance
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.text = text;

    // Find the voice by name
    const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    const targetVoice = voices.find(
      (voice) =>
        voice.name === "Microsoft Emily Online (Natural) - English (Ireland)"
    );

    if (targetVoice) {
      utterance.voice = targetVoice;
    } else {
      // Fallback: if the target voice is not available, use default voice
      utterance.voice = voices[0];
    }

    // Play the synthesized speech
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  });
}
```

- I attempted to use the onboundary event to change the color of individual words, but it didn't work as expected.
- I've tried a few approaches, including using timers and events, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired synchronization.
- every attempt led to the whole paragraph being red.
- The goal is to have each word change to red while it's being spoken, and revert to the original color when the word is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the required behavior by listening for the [`boundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/boundary_event) event on the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` instance. This event will give you a `charIndex` and `charLength` property which will indicidate where in the string the utterance is at that specific moment.

This allows you to grab a specific part from your string and wrap it in HTML -  like a `<mark>` tag in the example below - to highlight the current spoken text. Replace the text of the paragraph with the text with that includes the highlight.

Also listen for the [`end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/end_event) event to restore the original text in the paragraph when the utterance is finished.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('p');

function speakAndHighlightText(target) {
  const text = target.textContent;
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = text;
  
  utterance.addEventListener('boundary', ({ charIndex, charLength }) => {    
    const beforeWord = text.slice(0, charIndex);
    const word = text.slice(charIndex, charIndex + charLength);
    const afterWord = text.slice(charIndex + charLength, text.length);
    
    target.innerHTML = `${beforeWord}<mark>${word}</mark>${afterWord}`
  });
  
  utterance.addEventListener('end', event => {
    target.textContent = text;
  });
  
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}

speakAndHighlightText(target);
```

```css
mark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <p>"Sunsets paint the sky with hues of warmth, a daily masterpiece. Nature's farewell kiss, fleeting yet timeless, whispers serenity to all."</p>
</html>
```

I've also included a snippet which handles multiple paragraphs. The difference here is that `speakAndHighlightText` returns a `Promise` that resolves on the `end` event, which boils down to that we can *await* the speech to finish before moving to the next paragraph.

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('p');

const speakAndHighlightText = (target) => new Promise(resolve => {
  const text = target.textContent;
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = text;
  
  utterance.addEventListener('boundary', ({ charIndex, charLength }) => {    
    const beforeWord = text.slice(0, charIndex);
    const word = text.slice(charIndex, charIndex + charLength);
    const afterWord = text.slice(charIndex + charLength, text.length);
    
    target.innerHTML = `${beforeWord}<mark>${word}</mark>${afterWord}`
  });
  
  utterance.addEventListener('end', event => {
    target.textContent = text;
    resolve(target);
  });
  
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
});

(async () => {
  for (const target of targets) {
    await speakAndHighlightText(target);
  }
  
  console.log('Finished speaking');
})();
```

```css
mark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <p>"Sunsets paint the sky with hues of warmth, a daily masterpiece. Nature's farewell kiss, fleeting yet timeless, whispers serenity to all."</p>
  
  <p>Raindrops dance on leaves, a liquid symphony. Earth sighs in relief, embracing each droplet's embrace. Nature's lullaby, calming and pure.</p>
</html>
```